# Windows Phone - XNA & SIlverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-8

I was wondering if it is actually true that Microsoft is discontinuing XNA and Silverlight. If this is the case? What shall I learn to make applications for Windows Phone? What shall I learn to make simple/easy 2D based games (not c++)?

What are the alternatives with Windows 8?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official announcement from Microsoft that says they are discontinuing Silverlight/XNA.

Of course, a lot of us have our own reasons to believe that Silverlight is dying. I would not say the same about XNA. At least not yet :-) Don't forget XBox.

For the next version of Windows Phone (8), application programming model is going to be based on/same as Windows 8 (Win RT). And they have been promoting DirectX as a technology to develop games for Windows 8 (WinRT). *XNA* is officially not supported in Metro Mode.

To program games in DirectX, C++ is not the only option. Managed DirectX can be used with C#/VB. You can look into that.

And if you know Silverlight, your understanding on XAML would really help you a lot with new Metro Style apps (Phone and Windows). So, you don't have to worry about that part.

Answer (score 1):

For games it's better to use XNA, because eventually you'll start to create 3d games.
Silverlight is more adapted for common applications, like notepad, browser and other stuff.
And again, if you want to create games, learn more Xna.

Comment: I know what they both do. I've created applications on both platforms. My question is whether Microsoft is discontinuing XNA and Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say something about a rumor, but in this case the best thing that you can do is to stay in contact with Microsoft and its forums or social network.

For example http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/XNA-in-Windows-8

Windows Phone 8 will surely introduce a support for DirectX and C++, XNA is a subset, more or less, of DirectX, if Microsoft will introduce DirectX in its phones i see no point for keeping XNA; Silverlight is a technology that will never succeed at this point, even Flash is dead, you can imagine what is the situation about Silverlight that is a really really really small player in this market and it's not even portable.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no official statement yet, it's hard to say what will happen with those platforms. If you want to create games, you might consider using [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/).

> What is MonoGame?
>
> MonoGame is an Open Source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4
>   Framework. Our goal is to allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows &
>   Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux
>   and Windows 8 Metro.  PlayStation Mobile development is currently in
>   progress.

I had a demo of a few games made in MonoGame on Windows 8 last week and I gotta say I was pretty impressed.